# UITableView Cell Button mixed up

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a problem, setting a button to a `UITableviewCell`. 
After `viewDidLoad`, the button is on the right place. But when I am scrolling down, the button is anyplace else.

Here is my code, I hope you can help me. 
Thanks In Advance.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}

if (indexPath.section == 0 && indexPath.row == 0 && _isAddImageViewLoad == NO) {
    // Add Image Button
    UIButton *addImage = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    UIImage* image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"AddImage@2x"];
    addImage.frame = CGRectMake(110.0f, 10.0f, 110.0f, 110.0f);
    [addImage setImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [cell.contentView addSubview:addImage];
    _isAddImageViewLoad = YES;
} else {
    NSDictionary *dictionary = [_items objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    NSArray *array = [dictionary objectForKey:@"data"];
    NSString *cellValue = [array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = cellValue;
}

return cell;
```

}

Comment: Could you perhaps give some more information and make it a bit more clear what the problem is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a couple things.  If you use "AddImage" it will use the "AddImage@2x" automatically if it's a retina display. I don't think that will solve your issue but it could be causing weirdness.

When a table view cell is scrolled off the view it is "recycled" in a sense. It appears like you are using a bool to exclude the original cell from being loaded again with a button. You may want to use a header to hold your button if you always want it at the "top".  You may also want to verify that the button is being removed when the cell is reused. if its not it will show up in the next row that reuses that cell.

On a side note... Buttons don't usually work very well in table view cells because they handle touches in very different ways.  It's quite a bit of modification to get them to feel natural but that's another matter.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you very much. For my issue it was the best, to set a button to the header.

Comment: Glad I could help!  Interestingly enough I had an interview question recently and it was "How do you get a UIButton to work correctly in a UITableViewCell."  It was quite the question to work through :)

Answer (score 1):

It is because you are reusing the cells, and the button is getting placed when it shouldn't an easy solution in your else section. Write `addImage.hidden = YES;` and in your if statement put `addImage.hidden = NO;`

Answer (score 0):

Look at this line of code:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
```

This line of code means the `UITableViewCells` are not created every time. They are re-used as you scroll up and down. Using the code you have above, the `UIButton` will be created in the correct spot, but then as the cells are re-used, it will create the button in random spots.

One quick way to solve the problem, change the above line of code to simply

```
UITableViewCell *cell;
```

Comment: Then he isn't reusing cells and the scrolling performance will suffer

Comment: Instead of not reusing cell its better to use two seperate identifier for one with button and and other with not

Comment: That is an option too, but not reusing cells, definitely not an option

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because of cell reuse. You need to put some code in the else clause to delete the button if it exits. One way to do this, would be to give your button a tag, like:

```
addImage.tag = 10;
```

Then in your else clause:

```
}else{
    if (cell viewWithTag:10) [[cell viewWithTag: 10] removeFromSuperview];
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because of the dequeue for the cells.  The first time the tableview creates the cells, all the cells run through the

```
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
```

code.  But when the section 0 row 0 is moved off the screen, that cell is pushed into the cell reusable queue.

Now when your tableview needs to display section 0 row 0, it will get a cell from the reuse queue.  you will not get the same cell as the first time.  So now you might have 2 cells with the button.

What you should do is have different CellIdentifier for section 0 row 0 , and all other sections and rows.  Also create the button when creating the cell. So after the first time the tableView creates the cell, you will not be creating the the button everything.